jest mocked class always returning undefined
lets say i had the function
import { AddressRepository } from './address.repository';
import logger from '@common/utils/logger';
import { CreateAddressInput } from './interfaces/create-address-input.interface';

// Instantiate the repository once
const addressRepository = new AddressRepository();

export const createAddress = async (createAddressInput: CreateAddressInput) => {
  const fN = 'createAddress';

  const addressData = await getAddressData(createAddressInput);
  logger.info(`${fN} - Creating address with data: ${JSON.stringify(addressData)}`);

  const address = await addressRepository.createAddress(addressData);

  logger.info(`${fN} - Address ${address.id} created successfully`);
  return address;
};

my AddressRepository is a class and i was creating my test by:
// Mock the AddressRepository BEFORE importing the service
jest.mock('./address.repository', () => ({
  AddressRepository: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    createAddress: jest.fn() // Mocked method without implementation
  }))
}));

// Import necessary modules AFTER mocking
import * as AddressService from './address.service';
import { AddressRepository } from './address.repository';
import { CreateAddressInput } from './interfaces/create-address-input.interface';
import { Address } from '@prisma/client';
import { AddressData } from './interfaces/address.interface';

describe('AddressService - createAddress', () => {
  let addressRepository: jest.Mocked<AddressRepository>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks(); // Clear mock state between tests

    // Create a new mocked instance of the AddressRepository
    addressRepository = new AddressRepository() as jest.Mocked<AddressRepository>;

    // Inject the mocked repository instance into the service (if necessary)
    (AddressService as any).addressRepository = addressRepository;
  });

  it('should create a new address with geocode and timezone information', async () => {
    // Use the provided dataset
    const createAddressInput: CreateAddressInput = {
      streetNumber: '123',
      streetName: 'Main St',
      city: 'Anytown',
      province: 'ON',
      postalCode: '12345',
      country: 'Canada'
    };

    const mockAddressData: AddressData = {
      ...createAddressInput,
      latitude: 45.4215,
      longitude: -75.6972,
      timezone: 'America/Toronto',
      timezoneName: 'Eastern Daylight Time'
    };

    const mockCreatedAddress: Address = {
      id: '1',
      createdAt: new Date(),
      updatedAt: new Date(),
      unit: null,
      ...mockAddressData
    };

    // Spy on getAddressData and mock its return value
    jest.spyOn(AddressService, 'getAddressData').mockResolvedValueOnce(mockAddressData);

    // Mock the repository's createAddress method
    addressRepository.createAddress.mockImplementation(data => {
      console.log('createAddress called with:', data);
      return Promise.resolve(mockCreatedAddress);
    });

    // Call the service method (internally uses the mocked repository)
    const result = await AddressService.createAddress(createAddressInput);

    // Assertions
    expect(AddressService.getAddressData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(createAddressInput);
    expect(addressRepository.createAddress).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockAddressData);
    expect(result).toEqual(mockCreatedAddress);
  });
});


but the mocked repository is always being undefined. so it seems like my code at
    addressRepository.createAddress.mockImplementation(data => {
      console.log('createAddress called with:', data);
      return Promise.resolve(mockCreatedAddress);
    });

is not working as expected as it does not even show me the console log.
but if i was to mock it at the top by
jest.mock('./address.repository', () => ({
  AddressRepository: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    createAddress: jest.fn(() => {
      console.log('createAddress mock called');
      return Promise.resolve({ id: '1' });
    })
  }))
}));

it does not. i cant figure out why it is happening that way.
is it because it keeps on instantiating a different instance or something?

Change createAddress: jest.fn() to createAddress: createAddressMock
